# pandas group by a column, find min value of multiple columns, and create new column for the min row in group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe. I want the column to have the value "yes" for a specific `groupcol` value if the `datecol` column for that row is the earliest date. However, some groups have duplicate `datecol` values, so if there are duplicates of the earliest `datecol` I want to then use the earliest date from the column `publishcol`. At the end, each group value based off `groupcol` should only have one row where there is a new column with the value "yes".

This is what I have:

```
| groupcol | namecol | datecol    | publishcol |
| -------- | ------- | ---------- | ---------- |
|  A       | Bob     | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
|  A       | Ralph   | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-04 |
|  B       | Carl    | 2020-04-04 | 2020-04-04 |
|  B       | Joe     | 2020-04-04 | 2020-05-05 |
|  B       | Fred    | 2020-03-04 | 2020-07-21 |
```

This is what I want:

```
| groupcol | namecol | datecol    | publishcol | keep |
| -------- | ------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---- |
|  A       | Bob     | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 | yes  |
|  A       | Ralph   | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-04 | no   |
|  B       | Carl    | 2020-04-04 | 2020-04-04 | no   |
|  B       | Joe     | 2020-04-04 | 2020-05-05 | no   |
|  B       | Fred    | 2020-03-04 | 2020-07-21 | yes  |
```

Right now this is what I'm doing:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"groupcol": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
             "namecol": ["Bob", "Ralph", "Carl", "Joe", "Fred"],
              "datecol": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-04-04", "2020-04-04", "2020-03-04"],
              "publishcol": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-04", "2020-04-04", "2020-05-05", "2020-07-21"]
            })

# get min based off datecol
test['checkone']=np.where(
    test.datecol == test.groupby('groupcol')['datecol'].transform(min), 
    'want','drop')

# get min based off publish col
test['checktwo']=np.where(
    test.publishcol == test.groupby(['groupcol', 'datecol'])['publishcol'].transform(min), 
    'want','drop')

# get the final col
test['keep'] = np.where((test.checkone == "want") & (test.checktwo == "want"),
"yes", "no")
```

This gets me what I want, but it seems like a tedious way to do it. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go using `sort_values` on groupcol and the two dates columns. use the groupcol to check where not equal (`ne`) to the `shift` of itself that will give True on the min per groupcol.

```
s = test.sort_values(['groupcol', 'datecol', 'publishcol'])['groupcol']
test['keep'] = s.ne(s.shift())
print(test)
  groupcol namecol     datecol  publishcol   keep
0        A     Bob  2020-01-01  2020-01-01   True
1        A   Ralph  2020-01-01  2020-01-04  False
2        B    Carl  2020-04-04  2020-04-04  False
3        B     Joe  2020-04-04  2020-05-05  False
4        B    Fred  2020-03-04  2020-07-21   True
```

Note that I would keep a boolean column instead of the 'yes' and 'no'. but you can still use `test['keep'] = s.ne(s.shift()).map({True:'yes', False:'no'})` if you really want these values